# Thymeleaf 3.1 migration

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

i've an issue after migration that i not understand

in one on my pages i've this simple block

```
<th:block th:if="${param['var']}">
    <div>hello</div>
</th:block>
```

I expect that `<div>hello</div>` is rendered only if i add `var` query param, but this not working anymore (in previous thymeleaf version work). Why?

To obtain the same result now i must also check content in this way

```
<th:block th:if="${param['var'] != null && param['var'].length>0}">
    <div>hello</div>
</th:block>
```

I also add another strange thing
`<th:block th:if="${param['var'] && param['var'].length>0}">` return null pointer `param['var']` is not defined so...why `th:if="${param['var']}` not work but more strange `th:if="${param['var']!=null}`

So...i recap:

- works:

```
th:if="${param['var'] != null && param['var'].length>0}
```

- not works:

```
th:if="${param['var']}
th:if="${param['var'] != null}
```

Thanks for any help!